# Is cholla wood safe for a bug terrarium?

Tags: containment, terrariums, insects

**Specifically, is cholla wood safe for a lidded terrarium that will house springtails?**

I'm not going to put any vertebrates in there, just springtails and maybe isopods later on. I know cholla is reptile safe, but is it bug-safe?

Context: The terrarium is currently being used to root cuttings from houseplants; it's got potting soil, baby spider plants, *Philodendron* and pothos. I'm going to be adding springtails as a cleanup crew to help eating dead leaves since in my experience isopods do a bit "too well" in my setups; they breed like crazy and eat the plants. For that reason I'm just gonna use springtails by themselves. I was considering sprucing it up with a piece of cholla and a rock or two, but i can't remember if cholla is bug safe and Google isn't helping.